# How to update in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I update my data into my database? There is no error but it doesn't update in my database

This is my model

```
     public function updateNewServices($prod_name,$prod_id,$service_type,$service_gl_acc,$min_amnt,
                                $def_amnt,$max_amnt,$client,$services_id)
 {
    $services_id = $this->db->escape_str($services_id);
    $prod_name = $this->db->escape_str($prod_name);
    $prod_id = $this->db->escape_str($prod_id);
    $service_type = $this->db->escape_str($service_type);
    $service_gl_acc = $this->db->escape_str($service_gl_acc);
    $min_amnt = $this->db->escape_str($min_amnt);
    $def_amnt = $this->db->escape_str($def_amnt);
    $max_amnt = $this->db->escape_str($max_amnt);
    $client = $this->db->escape_str($client);
    $basic_data = array(
        "prod_name" => $prod_name,
        "prod_id" => $prod_id,
        "service_type" => $service_type,
        "service_gl_acc" => $service_gl_acc,
        "min_amnt" => $min_amnt,
        "def_amnt" => $def_amnt,
        "max_amnt" => $max_amnt,
        "client" => $client
      );

    $this->db->where("services_id=",$services_id);
    $this->db->update("services",$basic_data);
}
```

Comment: try this without `=` sign `$this->db->where("services_id", $services_id);`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: what is the result of this `print_r($basic_data);`?

Comment: please make sure you have the proper arrangement of parameter including $services_id on what happened with that id.

Answer (score 0):

1) First you should change line $this->db->where('services_id', $services_id);
2) second one you should check data type in database and update data  value type also .
3) You are using escape_str. so confirm with each data value data type and with db also.